# Understanding TypeScript Type System: Issue with Generated Arrays and Const Assertions

Tags: arrays, typescript, type-inference

I believe I'm facing a fundamental understanding issue with TypeScript, as evidenced by the behavior in the following code snippet. I'm trying to understand why a generated array isn't working and if there's a way to resolve this.

typescript

```
const mySlugs = ['post1', 'post2'] as const // working
const mySlugs = (allPosts.map(post => post._raw.sourceFileName)) as const  // not working
export type SlugType = (typeof mySlugs)[number]
```

The first line (const mySlugs = ['post1', 'post2'] as const;) works as expected, but the second line (const mySlugs = (allPosts.map(post => post._raw.sourceFileName)) as const;) doesn't (A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.ts(1355)).

Is there something I'm misunderstanding about TypeScript's type system or const assertions? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you expecting `as const` to mean in the second case?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Thank youI I added the error message. as const should give me the ability to create a union type like with the first line, which is working as expected. SlugType should become "post1" | "post2" in the second case the map Fuction gives back ['post1', 'post2'] Oh sorry for my EN, I hope it become clearer now. Thanks a million for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as const` assertion can only be used on simple literals, not expressions in general. From [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) for the release where it was added:

> **Caveats**
>
> One thing to note is that const assertions can only be applied immediately on simple literal expressions.

That's what the error message says as well:

> A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals. (1355)

If you want to make your generated array read-only, you can use the [`ReadOnlyArray` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type):

```typescript
const mySlugs = allPosts.map(post => post._raw.sourceFileName) as ReadonlyArray<string>;
```

But that only does one of the three things `as const` would do on a literal, so the result will be an array of `string`, not a tuple containing string literal types.

Comment: Thank you so much! This clarifies that I'll need to transition this code into a CLI tool to generate the types ahead of time. I now have a clear path forward.